# Conflict between executing AppImages and NTFS support. (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: mount, ntfs, appimage, fuse

A couple of days back, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on dev/sda5 after installing Windows 10 on a different partition dev/sda2 (so this is a dual boot). Everything was OK except that AppImages were not running.

At the moment I needed to run Balena Etcher AppImage. After some search I found out that AppImages depend on 'fuse' package to run, but installing 'fuse' breaks NTFS mount/read/write support by removing 'fuse3' and 'ntfs-3g' packages.

Reinstalling 'fuse3' and 'ntfs-3g' packages to get NTFS support removes 'fuse' 'libfuse2' thus rendering AppImages un-executable.

For the time being I have to install 'fuse' whenever I need to run AppImages, then I have to install 'fuse3' and 'ntfs-3g' whenever I need NTFS support.

So this is a continuous cycle. It would be very nice if there is a permanent solution to this issue.

PS: I never faced this issue in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: No I never used Ubuntu Core. Currently I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: @guiverc I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `fuse`-package to run appimages, only the package `libfuse2` is required.

It is the `fuse`-package, wich will remove `ntfs-3g` and `fuse3` and other packages, depending on your desktop environment.

Since you don't need `fuse`, don't install it, install only the `libfuse2`-package.

Comment: Thanks man! you made my day. It worked like a charm.